# Putting multi-dimensional array into a string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an `$_POST` array that looks like this.

```
Array (
    [burrito] => Cilantro
    [pizza] => Array ( [0] => Avocado [1] => Italian Sausage [2] => pepperoni )
)
```

I need `$_POST` variable to be dynamic. So, burrito & pizza is not fixed variable.

I want this to look like:

```
burrito=>Cilantro , pizza=>(Avocado, Italian Sausage, pepperoni)
```

I suspect I need to use:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    foreach($_POST[$key] as $d => $k){

    }

}
```

And the `implode()` function.

But I am stuck here. Whatever I do, the result would not come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `implode()`. But since you have values which only contain a string and some which contain an array, you have to check for that.

So you can do something like this:

Simply loop through your array and if the value `is_array()` then return the imploded array back, otherwise just the single value, e.g.

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => " . (is_array($v) ? "(" . implode(",", $v). ")" : $v) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Always love what you come up with Rizier!

Comment: Worked exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode() to convert an array into a string. Then your array will look like this:

```
{"burrito":"Cilantro","pizza":["Avocado","Italian Sausage","pepperoni"]}
```

You can also convert the string back into an array using `json_decode()`.

Comment: Thank you! This method does work beautifully but not 100% the way I want to look.